# Why does Java's socket.connect() consume 100% cpu resources?

Tags: network-programming, profiling, java

I created a threadpool and gave it 50 tasks to connect to a server. So once it was done connecting, sending some data over, then disconnecting. It also has a read timeout set at 5 seconds (5000 long of course). I even set the thread pool to a max size of 1. I then fire this up, on linux, and ran htop (a better version of top) to check the CPU usage. I consistently saw one of my cores (2 core machine) at 100% the entire time. I profiled this with hprof (`-agentlib:hprof=cpu=samples,interval=20,depth=3`) and had socket.connect() at 99%.

Here is what i find weird, isn't the point of blocking IO to block (hence wait) ? My JDK is (from `java -version`):

`OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.6.1) (6b16-1.6.1-3ubuntu3)`

`OpenJDK Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)`

**Update1**: this same problem occurs on Sun's JVM too:

```
java -version
Java version "1.6.0_20"
```

**Update2**: This is due to the doConnect method which is native. Anyone know how I can view the source for this native/C code?

**Update3**: I logged into windows to write the code and test it. It worked fine, no CPU resources being hosed. I log back into linux, and now the problem is still here, but not as sever as to hose the entire CPU core at 100% for just 1 connect.... Here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class SocketTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SocketTest();

    }

    public SocketTest() {

        ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(40);

        Vector<Callable<Object>> tasks = new Vector<Callable<Object>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++)
            tpe.submit(new Thread() {

                public void run() {
                    byte[] ip = { 74, 125, 19, (byte)((Math.random()*253)+1)};
                    Socket socket = new Socket();
                    try {
                        System.out.println("new thread: "+ip[3]);
                        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByAddress(ip), 80), 3000);
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        //no need to print
                    }
                }
            });

            try {
                tpe.invokeAll(tasks);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("test");
            try {
                //too lazy to write actual code to wait for task completness...
                tpe.awaitTermination(9001, TimeUnit.DAYS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("test2");
    }

}
```

Comment: There has to be something in the code, can you post the relevant parts. You will probably need to factor out to the lowest amount of code that gives you the problem.

Comment: see update2. It is occuring in the doConnect method inside of PlainSocketImpl. That is what is getting hosed. There isn't any method that I have which is eating up the CPU.....

Comment: 1500 threads, you must be kidding ? How do you know it is the connect ? Anyways doing it 1500 times is going to take a lot of resources.
If you are looking for 1500 concurrent connections then you better get something more robust than something you write.

Comment: @Romain Hippeau: "I even set the thread pool to a max size of 1"

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to comment that it looks like you are abusing the thread-pool, since you actually instantiate new objects of type Thread 1500 times, only to pass them to a thread-pool that instantiates more threads in order to run your tasks. What you should normally do is instantiate a Runnable and let the thread-pool do it's job. I'm not saying this is what causes the CPU to choke, but it surly is a problem.

Comment: I think the Threadpooling can be ignored here. I shouldn't have submitted an example with that in the code as it is not relevant and I am just lazy about that.

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the design issues with the code (for example, `tasks` is never really used), I could not reproduce the high CPU usage on either Windows or Ubuntu (`12.04.2 LTS`).

Can you please upgrade your `JDK` to 1.7 (`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`) and let me know which version of the `JDK` you are using? Mine is `javac 1.7.0_25`, for example (got using `javac -version`)

I will try to dig up further after that...